# Is it possible to use PostGIS for three-dimentional space?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I know that PostGIS is very good for geographic objects. Is it possible to use it in 3D or 4D and more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has support for 2D, 3DZ and 4D geometries. See:

- http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/ST_MakePoint.html
- http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/PostGIS_Special_Functions_Index.html#PostGIS_TypeFunctionMatrix